# Mysql insert with loop out of select statement

Tags: mysql, database, loops

I have a query which lists users IDs based on some criteria.

Now I want to insert every user ID into different table. I was thinking of a loop which would go through the list and insert a row one by one.

This is my select query:

```
SELECT s.id, s.name FROM students s
limit 10000;
```

How can I make a loop out of that. How to get to the values out of select statement in the loop?

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS loop_date;
DELIMITER //  
CREATE PROCEDURE loop_date()
BEGIN
DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 1; 
WHILE (number_of_students < 10000) DO
INSERT INTO users (student_id,student_name) VALUES (X?, Y?);
SET i = i+1;
END WHILE;
END;
//
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can INSERT ... SELECT in a single statement, instead of INSERT ... VALUES.

```
INSERT INTO users (student_id,student_name)
SELECT s.id, s.name FROM students s
limit 10000;
```

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html

Comment: It worked, I also had to add a constant value but did that with:
INSERT INTO users(student_id, university_id)
    SELECT s.id, '1' FROM students s